# jsp servlet form get value of checkbox/selection expression language

Tags: java, validation, jsp, servlets, webforms

I create a web application with jsp and servlets.

```
<p>
   <label>UserName:</label> 
   <input name="userName" type="text"  value="${param.userName}">
</p>
```

Usually I use Expression Language in order not to lose the entered information into forms (in case of an input error in another field).

It is also possible to use this method also in combination with selections and checkboxes?

Or do you have any other ideas?
I actually try to avoid this:

Servlet:

```
  if( request.getParameterValues("active") != null){
      request.setAttribute("vActive", "");
  }
```

JSP:

```
<input name="active" type="checkbox" <%  if ( request.getAttribute("vActive") != null ) { out.print(" checked=\"checked\""); }%> value="">
```

Comment: It's better to use Expression Language instead of scriptlets because we usually have all our markup (HTML) in JSP which forms the view part and the logic to retrieve data in Servlet, which forms the controller part in MVC. If you start writing java code in JSPs (or) writing html markup in servlets using `PrintWriter's println()`, you're back to square one and lose the whole principle of MVC and also it's a hell to maintain these snippets when you don't follow some pattern and place your code in JSPs and Servlets

Comment: That is (using Expression Language) what i'am trying to achieve, but I don't know how to use EL in combination with checkboxes and selections. Something like <input name="active" type="checkbox" ${param.active ? checked : ''} value="">

Comment: Maybe this link will help provide some clarity for you http://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-expression-language-el/

Comment: @user3740082.. I just posted my answer with EL to pre-select a checkbox, see if that helps :)

Comment: tried empty(param.active)?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pre-select a checkbox based on some value in request scope, then you can do it in EL like this

```
<input name="active" type="checkbox" value="Car" ${vActive != null ? "checked" : ""} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<input name="active" type="checkbox" ${empty(param.active) ? "" : "checked"} value="true">
```

And finally I understood how to use EL, thank you all.